# React bootstrap modal animation property changes doesnt apply as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, css-animations, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create custom ModalManager class and i have problem with showing/hiding animations.I would like to have control how modal will display/hide all the time,for example modal will show up with animation and hide without it.Is there any way to achive such a thing?

Here is some slim example of ModalManager

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
   super(props)
   
 this.displayModal = this.displayModal.bind(this)
  }
  
  render(){
  
   return (
    <div>
     <ModalManager ref={(c)=>{this.modalManager = c}} />
      <button onClick={this.displayModal}>display modal</button>
    </div>
    )
   
  }
  
  displayModal(){
  
   this.modalManager.display('LoadingModal')
    //fake ajax request
    setTimeout(()=>{
     
      this.modalManager.hide('LoadingModal',false) //hide without animation
     this.modalManager.display('NotificationModal',false) //display without animation
     
    },2500)
  
  }
 
}

class ModalManager extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
   super(props)
    this.hide = this.hide.bind(this)
    this.display = this.display.bind(this)
    
   this.state = {
    
     modals:{
       'LoadingModal':{
         constructor:LoadingModal,
          props:{
           animation:true,
           show:false,
           hide:this.hide
          }
         },
         'NotificationModal':{
         constructor:NotificationModal,
          props:{
           animation:true,
           show:false,
           hide:this.hide
          }
         }
       }
    
    }
    
  }
  
  render(){
   
    
    
   return(
    <div>
    {Object.keys(this.state.modals).map((key) =>{
     
       var Modal = this.state.modals[key].constructor,
      props = this.state.modals[key].props;
      
     return (
      
       <Modal key={key} modalKey={key} {...props}/>
      
      )
    
    })}
     
      </div>
    )
   
  }
  
  updateAnimation(key,value){
  
   this.setState((prevState)=>{
      prevState.modals[key].props.animation = value

     return {
      
       modals:prevState.modals,
      
      }
    
    })
  
  }
  
  display(key, animation = true){
  
   this.setState((prevState)=>{

      prevState.modals[key].props.animation = animation
     prevState.modals[key].props.show = true

     return {
      
       modals:prevState.modals,
      
      }
    
    })
  
  }
  
 
  
  hide(key,animation = true){
   this.setState((prevState)=>{
      prevState.modals[key].props.show = false
      prevState.modals[key].props.animation = animation

     return {
      
       modals:prevState.modals,
      
      }
    })
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
     this.setState((prevState)=>{
     prevState.modals[key].props.show = false
     return {
      
       modals:prevState.modals,
      
      }
    
    })
    },0)
   
  
  }
  
  

}

class LoadingModal extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
   super(props)
   
    this.hide = this.props.hide.bind(null,'LoadingModal',true)
  }
  
  render(){
  
   return(
    
    
       <ReactBootstrap.Modal {...this.props}>
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header >
            Loading Modal
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
          
           <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body >
            Loading...
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
          
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer >
            I will self close in a moment without animation
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
          
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
          
       
        
     
    
    )
  
  }

}

class NotificationModal extends React.Component {

 constructor(props){
   super(props)
   
    this.hide = this.props.hide.bind(null,'NotificationModal',true)
  }
  
  render(){
  
   return(
    
    
       <ReactBootstrap.Modal {...this.props}>
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header >
            Notification Modal
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
          
           <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body >
            Change modal without animation
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
          
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer >
          <button onClick={this.hide}>Hide me</button><br/>
            I should close with animation
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
          
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
          
       
        
     
    
    )
  
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App></App>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.2/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Its weird because my code work on first transition but when you press hide button it doesn't overwrite default animation property.I have also noticed that div with modal drop doesn't disappear after last modal hide.

Comment: you want it to hide without animation or with animation?

Comment: The last one should hide with animation,i want to have control how the modal will close.The ModalManager.display()/hide() method can recive optional parameter "animation" which will describe behaviour